# Delete laravel's controller, blades, etc. after installation

Tags: laravel, frameworks

i just made another Laravel project, but it is a little bit boring, to delete all the Laravel's files like app.blade, login.blade, contollers etc.

So i am asking, is there any option to delete them all or make Laravel project without it?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Ok, thanks, so i will keep removing this stuff by my boring manually way.

Comment: artisan fresh does not work anymore. Taylor has removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not following you. Laravel is all about jump starting the project. That's why all those controllers and views are already there. If you don't like the default Laravel file structure you may make your own as a git repo and use that to create new projects. There's nothing wrong with doing that. Except if there's a major update in the structure of the bootstrap file or the kernel.. etc. you will need to manually update them. Which is same for the official Laravel as well. Major updated come once a year (usually)